# Tf Serving - Docker from source or build from git?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

Struggling to understand the workflow here for tf serving.

Official docs say to “docker pull tensorflow/serving”. But they also say to “git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving.git”

1. Which one should I use? I assume the git version is so I can build my own custom serving image?
2. When I pull the official image from docker and run the container, why can’t I access the root? Is it because I haven’t “built it” properly yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have added some custom code, then clone first and then build image.
2. If you want to deploy image directly, pull image and run.
   BTW, what do you mean by "access the root"? AFAIC, root is the default user in a container.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a good observation.

1. Only place where I feel cloning Git hub repository using "https://github.com/tensorflow/serving.git" is required if you want to run the examples like 'half_plus_two', 'half_plus_three' or if you want to run the Examples mentioned in the link,
   https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/example.

Except that, as far as I know, pulling the Docker Image should do everything needed.

Even building the Custom Docker Image using our Custom Model doesn't need us to clone the Git hub repo.

Code for building Custom Docker Image is shown below:

```
sudo docker run -d --name sb tensorflow/serving

sudo docker cp /usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/Premade_Estimator_Export sb:/models/Premade_Estimator_Export

sudo docker commit --change "ENV MODEL_NAME Premade_Estimator_Export" sb iris_container

sudo docker kill sb

sudo docker pull tensorflow/serving

sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/TF_Serving/Premade_Estimator_Export,target=/models/Premade_Estimator_Export -e MODEL_NAME=Premade_Estimator_Export -t tensorflow/serving &

saved_model_cli show --dir /usr/local/google/home/abc/Jupyter_Notebooks/Premade_Estimator_Export/1556272508 --all

curl http://localhost:8501/v1/models/Premade_Estimator_Export #To get the status of the model
```

2. Regarding access to Root, if I understand it correctly, you don't want to run the docker commands using `Sudo` at the start for each command. Please follow the below mentioned command to get access to Root.

   i. Add docker group if it does not already exist

   ii. Add the connected user $USER to the docker group. Below are the commands to be run in the Terminal:

   sudo groupadd docker

   sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

   iii. Reboot your PC and you should be able to execute Docker commands without sudo.